# Comparing hand-written ADO/Sprocs w/nHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, ado.net

I am going back and forth between using nHibernate and hand written ado.net/stored procedures.

I currently use codesmith with templates I wrote that spits out simple classes that map my database tables, and it wraps my stored procedures for my data layer, and a thin business logic layer that just calls my data layer and returns the objects (1 object or collection).

This application is a web application, used for online communities (basically a forum).

I am watching summer of nhibernate videos right now.

Will using nHibernate make my life easier?  Will updates to the database schema be any easier? What effects will there be on performance?

Is setting up nhibernate, and ensuring it performs optimally a headache of its own?

I don't want a complicated or deep object model, I simply want classes that map my tables, and a way to fetch data from my other tables that have foreign keys to them.  I don't want a very complicated OOP model.

Answer (score 4):

NHibernate can definitely make your life easier. Updates to your database schema will definitely be easier, because when you use an ORM, you don't have an API of stored procedures hindering you from refactoring your database schema to meet changes in your business model.

OR mappers have a LOT to offer, and are sadly misunderstood by a significant portion of the developer community, and almost all of the DBA community.

Stored procedures in general give the DBA more options for tuning performance in a database, because they have the freedom to rewrite the stored proc so long as they don't change its output. However, in my experience, stored procedures are rarely rewritten, due to other issues that can arise as a result (i.e. when a deployment of a new version of software is performed, any modified versions of existing procs will overwrite the optimized version that was changed by a DBA...thus negating the benefit and creating a maintenance and unexpected performance issue problem.)

Another grave misconception (and this is primarily from the SQL Server camp...I have very little experience with Oracle), is that Stored Procedures are the only thing that can be compiled and the execution plan cached. As far as SQL Server is concerned, any parameterized query can and probably will be compiled and cached.

A benefit of OR mappers is that they are adaptive...with a stored procedure, you write a single statement that will be used regardless of contextual nuances when that query is executed. LINQ to SQL has an amazing capacity to generate the most efficient queries I've ever seen, and often throws DBA's for a serious loop. I've shown DBA's queries generated by L2S that were full of sub queries and unconventional things which were immediately scoffed at. However, given the challenge, the performance (namely physical reads) of a query written by a DBA that was supposedly superior ended up being significantly inferior (sometimes on a scale of 30 physical reads for L2S vs 400 physical reads for the DBA.)

Another detractor as far as DBA's are concerned is that, because ORM's generate dynamic SQL, they have no way to optimize those queries. On the contrary (and again, this is restricted to SQL Server), SQL Server offers a multitude of optimization paths (horizontal and vertical table partitioning, distribution of physical files accross disks for any table or view, indexes, etc.) that can be taken before the need to modify a query is a necessity. Even in the event that a query needs to be modified, SQL Server 2005 and later provide something called Plan Guides, which allow you to moderately tune any query (stored proc, strait sql, etc.). In the event that tuning a query isn't enough, you can match any particular query to a complete replacement query, allowing the DBA to tune the query as much as they need to (but as a last resort.)

There are many, many benefits that can be gained by using an OR mapper, and NHibernate is one of the best free ones (LLBLGen is also very nice, but is not free.) LINQ to Sql and Entity Framework are some new offerings from Microsoft (L2S is soon to be replaced by EF 4.0 from the .NET 4.0 framework...which will at least rival, if not outpace, NHibernate.) The biggest hurdle to adopting an ORM is usually not the ORM product itself, nor its capabilities or performance. The greatest hurdle is usually convincing your DBA (if your lucky/unlucky enough ... depends on your experience ... to have one) that an ORM can improve efficiency and reduce maintenance costs without a cost of optimization paths for the DBA.

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate works very well, especially for a simple model.  It will make your life much easier and isn't too tough to learn.  Look at "Fluent NHibernate" instead of using XML mappings, it is much easier.

Comment: Agreed, object attribute mapping is far simpler than XML mapping.  The only time you should ever be XML mapping is if your data objects are off limits or compiled.

Comment: Errr... Fluent NHIbernate isn't Attribute Mapping.  wiki.fluentnhibernate.org